# In C, should I be allowed to use pointers to arrays of incomplete types?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, incomplete-type

The IAR Embedded C compiler is happy with this, and I assumed it was correct C code:

```
struct incomplete;
typedef struct incomplete (*why_not)[2];
struct incomplete {struct incomplete *known_to_work;} array[2];
why_not ok = &array;
```

However, gcc and clang choke on the definition of `why_not`:

```
incomplete.c:2:29: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct incomplete’
 typedef struct incomplete (*why_not)[2];
                             ^
```

Technically, there is no reason to reject a definition of a "pointer to array of incomplete" type. After all, the structure definition is needed only where such a variable is dereferenced, or some pointer arithmetics is performed.

I'm eager to hide structure definitions where possible.

What does the C standard say about this?

Comment: You can't use a type "array of incomplete type" in any circumstance  (even function parameters)

Comment: @M.M Actually, why not?

Comment: File a bug report to IAR. Crap like this is the reason why I don't use their compiler. They have the stomach to demand that you pay them money in order to receive fixes for their non-compliance bugs. This is extra embarrassing since this part of C has been there since the 1980s.

Comment: @not-a-user because the standard says so

Comment: I tested with IAR ARM compiler, and I do get a warning, but only with strict mode enabled.

Comment: This is also a constraint violation in C for the same reason: `struct S; void f(struct S s[]);`  , even though `void f(struct S *s);` is correct, and would be equivalent if S were complete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code uses an array declarator where the element type is incomplete. This a constraint violation in ISO C, according to 6.7.6.2/1 **Array declarators**:

> **Constraints**
>
> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the `[` and `]` may delimit an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type.

Answer (score 6):

The following statement

```
typedef struct incomplete (*why_not)[2];
```

is a pointer to an array of two `struct incomplete`. The compiler does not know the size of `struct incomplete` yet, since it is not yet defined.

The following will however work:

```
typedef struct incomplete *why_not[2];
```

i.e.: an array of pointers to `struct incomplete`. The compiler does know the size of a pointer to an incomplete type (i.e.: it is just the size needed to store an address).

---

*Edit:*

The compiler does not need to know the size of `struct incomplete` in either case (as long as no pointer arithmetic is taking place), since both declarations are just declaring pointers.

Comment: The compiler does know the size of a pointer to an array of incomplete type as well, which is also just an address. As I pointed out, there is at least one compiler that does accept this. The question is, what does the standard (C99 or C11) say?

Comment: Addresses of different typed objects may have different sizes  (e.g. `int *` may be 2 bytes while `void *` is 3 bytes).

Comment: @M.M, in that case it should be *the compiler always know the size of a pointer to an incomplete type*